# Get Index of 2D Array in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, multidimensional-array

I have an ArrayList filled with objects in a 2D Array.  I want to get the indexes of the Object in the 2D Array at the index of the ArrayList.  For example:

```
Object map[][] = new Object[2][2];
map[0][0] = Object a;
map[0][1] = Object b;
map[1][0] = Object c;
map[1][1] = Object d;

List<Object> key = new ArrayList<Object>();
key.add(map[0][0]);
key.add(map[0][1]);
key.add(map[1][0]);
key.add(map[1][1]);
```

What I want to do is:

```
getIndexOf(key.get(0)); //I am trying to get a return of 0 and 0 in this instance, but this is obviously not going to work
```

Does anyone know how I can get the indexes of the 2D array at a specific position?  (The indexes are random).  Let me know if you have any questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly retrieve the index just because the index is used to access elements in `map` but they are not contained in the object. The object itself has no clue of being inside an array.

A better approach would be to store the index inside the object itself:

```
class MyObject {
  final public int x, y;

  MyObject(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

public place(MyObject o) {
  map[o.x][o.y] = object;
}
```

You can even have a wrapper class which works as a generic holder:

```
class ObjectHolder<T> {
  public T data;
  public final int x, y;

  ObjectHolder(int x, int y, T data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

and then just pass this around instead that the original object.

But, if you don't need to have them logically in a 2D array, at this point you can just use the wrapper without any 2D array.